# Cannot continue with python from a saved file in IDLE

Tags: python, file, python-idle

I am currently learning how to program in Python, everything was going well, I was using IDLE, so the code ran after you press enter. I saved the file with a '.py' ending, but now I've come back to it, it won't open. I tried to use 'edit with IDLE' in the right-click menu, but then I was just able to delete my old code, and when I wrote new code, it just wouldn't execute it. Anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: So you saved an interpreter session (i.e. with the `>>>`s in) as a `.py` file? An interpreter session isn't valid Python code, a Python script is a different thing. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Yes? No? Maybe? Could you give a [mcve] of the kind of file you're trying to execute?

Comment: Yeah, it is an interpreter session. the file type is just 'Python File'. When I just double click, it tries to open the command line, but then fails, but when I click edit with IDLE, it goes to the problem indicated in the question.

Comment: Oh and I am not trying to create a script, I just need to execute little junks of code seperate from each other, so it is okay if I cannot access the old code any more, I just want them to all be in the same file. Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the tutorial I linked - what you're describing sounds a lot like a module.

Comment: You can save an interpreter session as something.py, but it will not be a legal .py file.  Double clicking will fail.  Edit or Open with IDLE should work as long as you do not run.  What OS? If Windows, which one?  Which Python version?  Is it the only python on the system?